# Two constructors at in the same class with different parameters

Tags: java, android, constructor

In class 1 I make an instance :

```
  db = new AdapterDB (cal, rcarbohydrate, rfat, rprotein, getApplicationContext());
```

In class 2 I make an instace :

```
db = new AdapterDB (Bits, Truncation, Crossover, Mutation, Chromosomes, Generation, getApplicationContext());
```

In class AdapterDB I make the constructor :

```
private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    public AdapterDB(Context ctx)
    {
        this.context = ctx;
        DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper (context);
    }

    double Truncation;
    double Crossover;
    double Mutation;
    int Generation;

    private Context context;

    int indexOfChromosomes ;
    int indexOfGens;
    int gensNumber;
    int chromosomesNumber;

    String [][] population;
    double [] fitnesstotal;

    public AdapterDB(int Bits, double Truncation, double Crossover, double Mutation, int Chromosomes, int Generation, Context ctx)
    {
        this.indexOfGens = Bits;
        this.Truncation = Truncation;
        this.Crossover = Crossover;
        this.Mutation = Mutation;
        this.indexOfChromosomes = Chromosomes;
        this.Generation = Generation;
        this.context = ctx;
        DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper (context);

        population = new String[indexOfChromosomes][indexOfGens];
        fitnesstotal = new double [indexOfChromosomes];
    }

double cal;
    double rcarbohydrate;
    double rfat;
    double rprotein;

    public AdapterDB(double cal, double rcarbohydrate, double rfat, double rprotein, Context ctx)
    {
        this.cal = cal;
        this.rcarbohydrate = rcarbohydrate;
        this.rfat = rfat;
        this.rprotein = rprotein;
        this.context = ctx;
        DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper (context);
    }
```

At constructor the value still there, there is a value on each variable, but when I want use it in some function at class AdapterDB, cal, rcarbohydrate, rfat, and rprotein is zero (0.0) why this can happen? and how to solve it? Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure it's the same instance?

Comment: Yes it is only different at parameter

Comment: Can you describe the sequence of events that leads to the issue? What classes are involved, how the instance is created, where and when its passed, etc?

Comment: Hmm I wanna merge them into one class ...

Answer (score 4):

A good rule of thumb for any beginning programmer to keep in mind is the benefit that comes from having *classes* in the first place:

[What Is A Class? (From the Java Tutorials)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/class.html)

Your AdapterDB class is obviously trying to be two different things at once. I'm guessing your calling creating one instance using the first constructor, but then expecting other values (set by the second constructor) to be populated.

What you should probably do is make `AdapterDB` an abstract class:

```
public abstract class AdapterDB {

    private Context context;
    private DBHelper dbHelper;

    public AdapterDB(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        this.dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
    }

    public Context getContext() {
        return context;
    }

    public DBHelper getDBHelper() {
        return dbHelper;
    }
}
```

Then you can create separate classes for your individual types of data that you need to represent:

```
public class GeneticAdapter extends AdapterDB {

    int chromosomesNumber;
    // ... And others

    public GeneticAdapter(Context context, int numChromosomes, ...) {
        super(context);
        // Set your instance variables
    }
}
```

And one for fitness?

```
public class FitnessAdapter extends AdapterDB {
    double cal;
    // ... And others

    public FitnessAdapter(Context context, double cal, ...) {
        super(context);
        // Set your instance variables
    }
}
```

My apologies if this isn't what your looking for, your question was a bit difficult to understand. Best of luck, comment below (or edit your answer) if you have follow-ups.

Comment: But I want to make it in one class, may I?

Comment: Technically you probably can find a way, but I don't think it's a very good idea in this case. It will give you headaches down the road. I know when you're starting out it's tempting to find the easiest, shortcut-iest solution, but please take time to do things right.

Comment: The problem is if I make it into some classes, there will be another error because mine is related with database too, last time I have already tried it but I can't solve the error, I have no much time >_< Thx u

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think we have enough to go on here - we need to see how/why these instances are being created, why you need two of them, why they're being stored in the same class, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're creating two separate instances and trying to merge them by giving them the same name. This is not how Java works.

Class 1 makes an adapterdb (called db), with the given parameters.

Class 2 makes another adapterdb with the given parameters.

If DB is a global variable of some sort which both classes can access, the reference DB points to the NEW object, and the first object is garbage. The second call to the constructor does not merge the two together.

The constructors seem like they belong to two different classes: typically, a constructor will set all instance variables to at least some default value.

If yo do want to 'merge' the two, I would use the default constructor and turn the two constructs you have into large setter methods like so:

```
public AdapterDB(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    this.dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
}

public setFitness(double cal, double rcarbohydrate, double rfat, double rprotein, Context ctx) {
    ...
}

public setGenetics(int Bits, double Truncation, double Crossover, double Mutation, int Chromosomes, int Generation, Context ctx) {
    ....
}
```

However, because the parameters are so different, I would be wary about structuring the class as you are and I would see if the solution proposed by craig is not a more suitable option.

Comment: May you give me an example of use the default constructor and turn the two constructs you have into large setter methods ? Thx u

Comment: how can they become setFitness and setGenetics? Thx u

Answer (score 0):

You can call another constructor using `this` keyword.

```
class Animal {
    int weight;
    String name;

    Animal(int w) {
        weight = w;
    }

    Animal(String n) {
        this(10);  // set the weight to 10
        name = n;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, no. I mean that the problem is the name = n it has no value